# Hiding MS Access from background and taskbar

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am looking forward to hide the Access background of my project when it's running to give it a more professional look and make it running like a standalone application. I am using Access 2003 and a form is already opening when the project is loaded. I would like to add some code in the `Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)` of that form to hide the Access background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work on older versions of Access (tested on Access 2003):

```vb
Option Compare Database 
Option Explicit 

Global Const SW_HIDE = 0 
Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1 
Global Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2 
Global Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3 

Private Declare Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" _ 
Alias "ShowWindow" (ByVal hWnd As Long, _ 
ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long 

Function fSetAccessWindow(nCmdShow As Long) 

    Dim loX As Long 
    Dim loForm As Form 
    On Error Resume Next 
    Set loForm = Screen.ActiveForm 

    If Err <> 0 Then 
        loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow) 
        Err.Clear 
    End If 

    If nCmdShow = SW_SHOWMINIMIZED And loForm.Modal = True Then 
        MsgBox "Cannot minimize Access with " _ 
        & (loForm.Caption + " ") _ 
        & "form on screen" 
    ElseIf nCmdShow = SW_HIDE And loForm.PopUp <> True Then 
        MsgBox "Cannot hide Access with " _ 
        & (loForm.Caption + " ") _ 
        & "form on screen" 
    Else 
        loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow) 
    End If 
    fSetAccessWindow = (loX <> 0) 
End Function
```

Just call `fSetAccessWindow(0)` to hide and `fSetAccessWindow(1)` to show. Alternatively,  use `fSetAccessWindow(2)` and `fSetAccessWindow(3)` to show minimized/maximized. You can use the `Global Const` too. Be careful: Access will be hidden from the taskbar.

If it doesn't work with Access 2010, here is another code that could work: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=2562

**The forms must be modal** or it won't work. If for some reason you messed up and Access is still running in background but not showing in the taskbar or the task-manager, double click on any Access project again (nothing will happen because Access is still running) and then press ALT+TAB to reach the Access icon (it should magically show up). Nothing happens again because it's hidden, but it's now possible to close it with ALT+F4 if it still has the focus, thus preventing you from rebooting your computer...

Comment: It's hidden from there too (as stated in my post).

Comment: (only when all forms are unloaded/hidden)

Answer (score 0):

In Ms Access 2003 a simple way seem to make the form 
1. pop up
2. border style none
3. On form load event run maximise command

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   DoCmd.Maximize
End Sub
```